# Show that $(a,b]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},b]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to verify the following: $$(a,b]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a+\frac{1}{n},b\right]$$ 
Set inclusion one way is easy, but how can I show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},b]\subset(a,b]$

I tried the following if $x\notin\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},b]$ then $\forall\,n$: $x<a+\frac{1}{n}$, implying $\frac{1}{k}<-x+a+\frac{1}{n}$, (for some $k$ by the Archimedian property), now I could claim $\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{k}$, then I would be done. But is this motivated? Can I take limits in this process? Or is there an other method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're working this the wrong way. If you want to show $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},b]\subset(a,b]$, you usually start by either choosing a point $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n},b]$ or for contradiction a point $x \not\in (a, b]$.

Comment: You are right, I should have started from $a,b]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a + \frac{1}{n} > a$, then $\big(a+\frac{1}{n}, b\big] \subseteq (a, b]$ for all $n$ and the union is a subset as well. So this is the easy way, no?

For the other inclusion, suppose that $x \in (a,b]$. Then $x > a$ and there must exist an integer $m$ such that $x > a + \frac{1}{m}$, so

$$x \in \Big(a + \frac{1}{m}, b\Big] \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Big(a + \frac{1}{n}, b\Big].$$